# Django Prefetch with custom queryset which uses managers method

Tags: python, django

Let's look at example from django docs with Pizza and Topping models.
One pizza may have multiple toppings.

If we make a query:

```
pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related('toppings')
```

We'll get all the pizzas and their toppings in 2 queries.
Now let's suppose that I want to prefetch only vegetarian toppings (assume we have such property):

```
pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('toppings', queryset=Topping.objects.filter(is_vegetarian=True))
)
```

It works pretty well and Django doesn't perform yet another query for each pizza, when making something like this:

```
for pizza in pizzas:
    print(pizza.toppings.filter(is_vegetarian=True))
```

Now let's suppose We have a custom manager for Topping model and we decided to put there a method that allows us to filter only vegetarian toppings like in code example above:

```
class ToppingManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_vegetarian(self):
        return self.filter(is_vegetarian=True)
```

Now I make a new query and prefetch custom queryset with my method from manager:

```
    pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('toppings', queryset=Topping.objects.filter_vegetarian()))
```

And the try to execute my code:

```
    for pizza in pizzas:
        print(pizza.toppings.filter_vegeterian())
```

I get a new one query for each iteration of the loop.
That is my question. Why?
Both these constructions return the same type object which is queryset:

```
   Topping.objects.filter_vegetarian()
   Topping.objects.filter(is_vegetarian=True)
```

Comment: If you do the prefetch using the manager method but then in your for loop do print(pizza.toppings.filter(is_vegetarian=True)), does it make the extra queries? I have a feeling I understand why this is happening, just want to make sure it operates as I imagine it does.

Comment: I started to debug it and it seems like even in ther first example we'll have a loope of queries too. That is why docs recommend to use us to_attr

Comment: But it's still interesting. Why not to implement this feature in django? If prefetched queryset is the same as filtered after we can still use cached results

Comment: Honestly, I think the reason is that it would be even harder to follow the logic and would make development a nightmare for anyone who didn't work directly on it when it was implemented. You have to remember, Django is open source and as such, a certain number of people need to be able to understand it (it doesn't have to be a large number). Since you query a model, and the queryset returns models, having the models it returns then contain their own querysets with already-executed lookups could be dizzying to think about and troubleshoot, especially if you have a more complicated prefetch.

Comment: You could definitely look at adding it yourself though! It seems like a niche but potentially useful feature, perhaps if you can code it simply enough to follow along with, the core team would consider adding it in.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't tested this directly, but you should not invoke a method or filter again in the loop, as prefetch_related has already attached the data. So either of these should work:

```
pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('toppings', queryset=Topping.objects.filter(is_vegetarian=True))
)
for pizza in pizzas:
    print(pizza.toppings.all()) # uses prefetched queryset
```

or

```
pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('toppings', queryset=Topping.objects.filter_vegetarian(),
             to_attr="veg_toppings"))
for pizza in pizzas:
    print(pizza.toppings.veg_toppings)
```

Your examples do not work because they invoke another queryset, and this cannot be compared to the prefetched one to determine if it would be same.

It also says so [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related):

> The `prefetch_related('toppings')` implied `pizza.toppings.all()`, but `pizza.toppings.filter()` is a new and different query. The prefetched cache can’t help here; in fact it hurts performance, since you have done a database query that you haven’t used.

and

> Using to_attr is recommended when filtering down the prefetch result as it is less ambiguous than storing a filtered result in the related manager’s cache.

Comment: I like this, but I have one big question. What kind of thing should `veg_toppings` override? If I did not apply this high-specific `prefetch_related`, then I would like to obtain the same contents with a new query, otherwise it violates good practices for reusability. If I could set an attribute to a custom manager, then I would prefer to somehow prefetch that directly, instead of re-writing the behavior for the purposes of optimization.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation:

```
class ToppingManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_vegetarian(self):
        return self.filter(is_vegetarian=True)
```

Looks non-standard. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/) look like they do a safer method of modifying the super-class method for this sort of lazy-eval stuff. If I rewrite your method in that style, it would look like:

```
class ToppingManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_vegetarian(self):
        return super(ToppingManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_vegetarian=True)
```

You wouldn't strictly need the super() here, but safer to use it because you should *know* that you want to start with the models.Manager get_queryset method.

Doing a brief test of this in my own environment, I find that it works feeding into `Prefetch` without triggering queries on each item. I do not have any reason to believe this would not work for the problem here.

However, I'm also inclined to believe that specifying `to_attr` in webjunkie's answer may also be necessary.